# Control specific axis ranges in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

I have a question controlling the axes in R.

I have a set of number (Like below) and I would like to empathise a specific range, **but the rest of the data points are still in the figure.**

For example, I want to empathise the number higher than x = 40, y = 40, located at the top right and accounted for 70% of the figure, and sizing the rest of the numbers in the rest of the other areas (30%).
Therefore, how can I control the number range (40-50 = 70% of total area, 0 - 40 = 30% of the total area)in the axes?

```
# Create dummy dataset
df.test_data <- data.frame(x_var = 1:50 + rnorm(50,sd=15),
                           y_var = 1:50 + rnorm(50,sd=2))
# Plot data using ggplot2
ggplot(data=df.test_data, aes(x=x_var, y=y_var)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: that's just one dup. many dups.

Comment: Edited. The question was to keep all the data points but have a bigger portion of one specific range.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help You in some way:

```
df.test_data <- data.frame(x_var = 1:50 + rnorm(50,sd=15),
                       y_var = 1:50 + rnorm(50,sd=2))

ggplot(data=df.test_data, aes(x=x_var, y=y_var)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(40,50,1), limits = c(40, 50)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(40,80,1), limits = c(40, 50))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to keep all the data points but have a bigger portion of one specific range. @Sin